# Electrum hangs when sending bitcoins

Tags: electrum, sending

I am using Electrum and when sending bitcoins I got a small window with a "Please Wait..." message, the problem is that it has been more than 1 hour and nothing happened! The window is still there and I can tell from [blockchain.info](http://www.blockchain.info) that the bitcoins is not received at the destination.

- Is it normal?
- what is the correct behavior expected?
- Should i close the "Please wait..." window and re-send the coins?

Answer (score 2):

Try resarting the client, switching servers and make sure that you are connected to a server (green ball in the bottom-right corner) before making a tx